# Motivating Mathematics Movies

Tags: student-motivation

A teacher has recently asked me to provide some suggestions for math movies to screen for a set of high school seniors. My first inclination was [Flatland](http://www.flatlandthemovie.com/) before I decided to do some basic searching. I came across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_about_mathematicians) list, as well as the movies [The Colours of Infinity](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0241317/) and [N is a Number](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125425/)--both seem interesting--but I can't help but think I might be missing something. Does anybody else have any other suggestions?

Comment: "Donald in Mathmagic Land" is a fun one if you haven't seen it before.  There are lots of uploads of it on youtube

Comment: A lot of us in the U.S. would like to send Donald to Mathmagic Land...and any other land that might take him.

Comment: Do you also consider http://www.dimensions-math.org/Dim_E.htm as a movie?

Answer (score 6):

There is a list at [**The Mathematical Movie Database**](http://www.qedcat.com/moviemath/) that includes (for some of the entries) the relevant time stamps and dialogue. I found the site by looking for one particular movie:

> [**It's My Turn**](http://www.qedcat.com/moviemath/its_my_turn.html) (1980) [**IMDB**](http://imdb.com/title/tt0080936/) ***** Light romantic movie about a female mathematician. Famous among mathematicians because the full proof of the Snake Lemma is given in the first scene.

(I learned of this reference several years ago in [**MO 106943**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/106943): *Who named it the Snake Lemma?*)

There's another list called [**Mathematics in Movies**](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/mathmovies/) that was included among others at [**MO 77279**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77279).

Comment: Ah, this is the movie I was shown via VHS-tape during my topology course.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend [Between the Folds](http://www.greenfusefilms.com/), on origami, math, and science.

Comment: Everyone should see it!!